# Mongo can't connect

Tags: mongodb, azure

I'm running Ubuntu 15 on an Azure VPS. I installed MongoDB and got it up and running fine. Then, I stopped the `mongod` service and I changed the db path and log path in `mongod.conf` to point to directories I've created on an attached disk:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /datadrive/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /datadrive/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

I restarted the entire VPS to make double sure the new changes take effect. Now when I type `mongo` I get the following error:

```
2016-02-05T14:49:41.004+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-02-05T14:49:41.018+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:224:14
@(connect):1:6
```

If I reverse my changes and use the original `log` and `lib` locations, it works. What can I do to make sure the new locations are used?

**Edit**

After keeping the old log location and trying the above steps, I get the following in the log:

```
2016-02-05T15:19:47.049+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1158 port=27017 dbpath=/datadrive/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=CLIENTPROJECTS
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.1
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-02-05T15:19:47.146+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/datadrive/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-02-05T15:19:47.693+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /datadrive/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2016-02-05T15:19:47.693+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: Any logs when mongodb starts? It seems the account running mongod does not have persmissions on the new directories.

Comment: @Peter No logs. It's not using the new log location. Any ideas?

Comment: Keep the old log location to see what goes wrong

Comment: @Peter good plan. Give me a couple of mins to test.

Comment: @Peter I've added what logs out. Looks like a permissions issue indeed but not sure what it's meant to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can check if mongod started: `sudo lsof -i | grep 27017` and then check what's in the log `/datadrive/log/mongodb/mongod.log`.

**EDIT:**

Stop all instances of mongod (`ps aux | grep mongod` should show nothing's running), remove lock file `rm /datadrive/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`, and restart the service.

**EDIT2:**

Directories from the config `/datadrive/lib/mongodb/` and `/datadrive/log/mongodb/` should exist and belong to mongodb user. By default it is `mongodb:mongodb`, and is defined in `/etc/init.d/mongodb` as  `DAEMONUSER`.

Comment: There's no log created at that location because the whole problem is the new paths for lib and log. It's not happy using the new paths, so it's not logging to it.

Comment: I created the new locations with `sudo mkdir` so they have root user and group. They both have 755 permissions.

Comment: The new lib and log I created are empty. The old ones have the old log and files in

Comment: They really should belong to `mongodb:mongodb` or whatever user is specified in the config.

Comment: I've edited my question with the log of the issue. Not sure where to go from here though

Comment: There's no lock file. I think the issue is that my new directories dont belong to mongodb:mongodb so I'm just trying that now

Comment: We're in business! Finally got this to work after changing the user and group for the new directories as suggested. Thanks for your help